# How to make the TextView invisible when there are items in listView?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I like to display textView when there are no items in the listView whereas the textView will not display when there are items in the listView. My problem is even there are items in the listView, the textView still will be displayed in a short time and then load the items into listView. So, how to make the TextView invisible when there are items in listView?

Here is the codes:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_screen);
    user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("user");
    Log.d("dg",user);
    getList();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    lv.setEmptyView(emptyText);       
}

public void getList(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.kryptoquest.com/tracker/friendlist.php");
                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", user));
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error:"+e.toString());
            }

            //convert response to string
            try{
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                            sb.append(line + "\n");

                    }
                    Log.d("test",sb.toString());
                    is.close();

                    result = sb.toString();

                    result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);                    
                //    Log.d("result",result);
                    friend = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result.split("[*]")));   
                  Log.d("size",String.valueOf(friend.size()));
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run(){
                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ThirdActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,friend);
                            setListAdapter(adapter); 
                        }
                    });


            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

list_screen.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<TextView   android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/no_friend"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what in getList();? it`s return any value.

Comment: you can check by putting the condition the if(getList.size()>0) then show listview else show textView

Comment: I answered a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212137/change-color-of-an-item-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/17124508#17124508

and here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374226/setting-tag-for-listview-item-when-using-simpleadapter/17124755#17124755

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is even there are items in the listView, the textView still will be displayed in a short time and then load the items into listView.

Don't use `setEmptyView()` in `onCreate()`, but add `android:visibility="gone"` to the TextView in your XML and use `setEmptyView()` *after* calling `setAdapter()`.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ThirdActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,friend);
setListAdapter(adapter); 
lv.setEmptyView(emptyText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple with an `if` statement something like

```
if (listView.getSize() > 0){
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //or use
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    //your list is empty
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

of curse you need to call this after adding the `adapter` to your `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here:

[Setting tag for listview item when using SimpleAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374226/setting-tag-for-listview-item-when-using-simpleadapter/17124755#17124755)

and here

[Change color of an item in ListView with SimpleAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212137/change-color-of-an-item-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/17124508#17124508)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide textView if there a list items with a useful method:
AdapterView.setEmptyView (View emptyView)

This is an example:
ListView listView;
TextView textView;

listView.setEmptyView (textView);
This will hide textView automatically when there are items in the list and display textView when the listView is Empty!